# Determining operating system of the host using python-nmap

Tags: nmap, python

Until Python 3.4 you were able to determine target's operating system with
Python as follows:

```
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner()
scanner = nm.scan(IP, port, arguments='-O')
print(scanner['scan'][IP]['osmatch'])
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and `osmatch` returns nothing.
Is there a way how to go about this ?

Comment: You will have to go through the field definitions in the python `nmap` module. This is a python question, not an nmap question.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your script with Python 3.7.6:

```
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner()
scanner = nm.scan(IP, port, arguments='-O')
print(scanner['scan'][IP]['osmatch'])
```

and it works well. The problem you have is that, for some reasons, the scan didn't retrieve any result, and the result object is empty, but if you try again on a different host it should work.